# How to access F# results from C#

Tags: c#, f#

First of all, I am new to F#, so sorry if this question already has answers here (I've tried looking around, but couldn't find what I was looking for). With this out of the way, let's go to my issue...

I am trying to access F# results from C#, but these are strange. Here's my F# code:

```
namespace SimpleFSharpCode

module SFSC =
    let num1: int = 1
    let num2: int = 2
    let add (n1: int) (n2: int) = n1 + n2
    let sum2: int = add num1 num2

    let sum3 =
        let num3: int = 1
        let num4: int = 2
        let add2 (n1: int) (n2: int) = n1 + n2
        add2 num3 num4

    let sum4 num5 =
        let num6: int = 6
        let add3 (n1: int) (n2: int) = n1 + n2
        add3 num5 num6

    printfn "num1 = %i" num1
    printfn "num2 = %i" num2
    printfn "sum2 = %i" sum2
    printfn "sum3 = %i" sum3
    printfn "sum4 = %i" (sum4 5)
```

It yields the results:

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 2
sum2 = 3
sum3 = 3
sum4 = 11
```

Here's my C# code:

```
using SimpleFSharpCode;

var num1 = SFSC.num1;
var num2 = SFSC.num2;
var sum1 = SFSC.add(num1, num2);
var sum2 = SFSC.sum2;
var sum3 = SFSC.sum3;
var sum4 = SFSC.sum4(5);

Console.WriteLine("num1 = " + num1);
Console.WriteLine("num2 = " + num2);
Console.WriteLine("sum1 = " + sum1);
Console.WriteLine("sum2 = " + sum2);
Console.WriteLine("sum3 = " + sum3);
Console.WriteLine("sum4 = " + sum4);
```

It yields the results:

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 2
sum1 = 3
sum2 = 0
sum3 = 0
sum4 = 11
```

As you can see, `sum2 = sum3 = 0`, which is not what I would expect. I would instead expect `sum2 = sum3 = sum1 = 3`, as is the case when I execute the F# script directly. What's strange is that `sum4 = 11`, which is the result I expect.

With this in mind, I wonder:

1. Why are `sum2 = sum3 = 0` in my C# code but not in the F# code?
2. How should I write my code such that `sum2 = sum3 = 3` when I call the C# script; i.e. how do I access the F# results from my C# script?

Comment: Are you compiling your F# into an assembly and calling it from there? What platform, IDE, and version of .NET is this?

Comment: No, I'm simply referencing the F# project from csproj. I'm executing this on Windows 10, using vscode (with dotnet cli) and the .NET version is net7.0 (for both of the F# and C# projects).

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with when code runs. The F# and the C# code shown here seems to be initialization code that runs before the main program. If the C# code is moved to a method that is called from the C# main method, then perhaps also the C# output will make sense.

Comment: I set this up in Visual Studio 2022 and it works for me. Here is the output: `num1 = 1
num2 = 2
sum1 = 3
sum2 = 3
sum3 = 3`
sum4 = 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some good comments from @Bent Tranberg and @Jim Foye to point me in the right direction, I managed to figure it out...

It turns out that the problem was in the .fsproj file. Basically, I had it setup as a console project (which was necessary in order to execute the F# script from F#), but it **has** to be a class project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- <OutputType>Exe</OutputType> --> // <-- THIS HAS TO BE COMMENTED OUT OR REPLACED 
                                          //       WITH <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When the `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` is commented out, the C# script generates the following result:

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 2
sum2 = 3
sum3 = 3
sum4 = 11
num1 = 1
num2 = 2
sum1 = 3
sum2 = 3
sum3 = 3
sum4 = 11
```

Note that the `printfn` commands in the F# project are now also printed.